# What are the Xlib header files and how can I install them?

Tags: debian, terminal, x11, compiling

Wanted to try out `st` terminal. In the Requirements section in its `README`:

```
Requirements
------------
In order to build st you need the Xlib header files.
```

1. What are 'Xlib' & 'Xlib header files'?
2. What packages should I install? Using Debian stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xlib is the X11 client library, and the headers are files needed to build programs using it. On Debian you need to install `libx11-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

In debian the relevant Xlib header and the Xlib files are located at:

```
/usr/include/X11
```

and

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

respectively. When building st from the suckless source, it is necessary to alter the locations of the lib and header files suckless provide in the config.mk file to those which are relevant for a debian build. Once altered, st should build successfully. So inside the config.mk file, the following included changes in the code works:

```
X11INC = /usr/include/X11

X11LIB = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

#X11INC = /usr/X11R6/include

#X11LIB = /usr/X11R6/lib
```